# Angular JS Dropdown based on another textbox

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an requirement in angularJs like based on one dropdown I needs to populate another textbox value.

```
<tr>
<th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AName, new { @class="required" })</th>
<td>
<div>Select a value from the list</div>                       
<div class="field-validation-error" ng-repeat="error in ValidationResults.AName">{{error}}</div>
<select ng-model="aData.AName">
<option></option>
<option ng-repeat="item in Ad | uniqueFields:'AName' | notEmptyString: 'AName'">{{item.AName}}</option>
</select>
</td>`
</tr>
```

The above is first dropdown, Based on the selection of this one i needs to fill the other text box.

```
<tr>
<td>
<div>Give a new value or select it from the list.</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="aData.Vendor">                
</td>
```

aData is the data colelction from the oracle table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="aData.Vendor" ng-value="{{ aData.AName }}">
```

So it's using ng-value in order to change the text shown in the text input. Try it and let me know if it works because I am not 100% sure but I think it will work.